# How do I approach this ideal op-amp problem?

Tags: operational-amplifier

This op-amp problem has been giving me issues. I see two inverting op-amp circuits which I'm sure I should be able to use to simplify this problem, but that 10k resistor at the top is making the analysis difficult. Since that resistor is there, doesn't it change the output of the first op-amp?

How do I approach this?
[image]

Comment: You will have to write the equations- each op amp has negative feedback around it and there is overall positive feedback that counteracts the negative feedback to one degree or another ( for you to figure it out)

Comment: I think it should be completely solved by applying nodal analysis at each op-amp's inverting input. From there it's just algebra to get V2 as a function of V1. The ideal op-amp's virtual short and infinite input impedance greatly simplify the analysis here.

Comment: Isn't the voltage at the inverting inputs just 0 though?

Comment: You're on the right track. If you can't use _voltage_ you'll have to use _________.

Comment: Mesh current analysis?

Comment: Remember: Nodal Analysis <=> KCL, Mesh Analysis <=> KVL. If you haven't done it already, it may be helpful to solve the simple inverting or non-inverting op-amp circuit by hand first. The same techniques you use will apply to this circuit as well.

Comment: So if I name the node into and out of the first op-amp A and B, respectively, and the node at the input of the right op-amp C, I get these KCL equations: $$\frac{-v_1}{10}+\frac{-v_B}{5}+\frac{-v_2}{10}=0$$ and $$\frac{-v_B}{5}+\frac{-v_2}{12}=0$$. After simplification, I get $$v_2=-6v_1$$. Is that right?

Comment: I do believe you've got it!

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2cNYA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Because the Op-amps are ideal.

KCL at node 1 :

(0-V1)/10 + (0-Vout1)/5 + (0-V2)/10 = 0

<=>  -V1 -2Vout1 -V2 = 0                (1)

KCL at node 2 :

(0-Vout1)/5 + (0-V2)/12 =0

<=> Vout1 = -5/12 V2                    (2)

Sub (2) into (1) we have :

-V1 + (5/6)V2   - V2 = 0

=> V1 = -1/6 V2
<=> V2 = -6 V1

Comment: We try not to directly answer questions like this, but rather to lead the asker to the answer.

Comment: Agreed. Tim, if you read the comment trail on the OP you'll see a few gentle prompts from us and the OP was able to figure it out him/herself. This site uses [MathJAX](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/most-common-mathjax-uses-in-electrical-engineering) to make formulas readable. You may as well tidy up your post with MathJAX. Someone other than the OP may benefit.

Comment: This analysis provides gain from v1 to v2, but ignores the fact that there's positive gain of 1.2 in the closed loop, so this circuit is not stable and simply won't work as assumed. A DC stability analysis is a prerequisite to further analyses that assume ideal op-amps; they make no sense and it's an error to perform them on an unstable circuit. To see the lack of stability, assume some open-loop gain *A* for each op-amp, and then attempt to calculate the output of the system in the limit as A→∞, with arbitrary v1. The math involved is high school intro to calculus only, nothing hard.

Comment: IOW, you forget that the op-amp output equations, like "vout=vin*-Rf/Rin" are the **results** of taking limits with op-amp open loop gain *A* →∞; they are finite and thus assume that the circuit was stable to begin with. If you don't know if the circuit is stable (here you don't!), you must write the equations with an explicit open-loop gain *A*, then take the limit as *A* →∞, and see that you get finite results.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit is a little bit tricky because it has positive feedback, that dominates the overall behavior. Basically it is a Schmitt-Trigger and therefore has hysteresis.

The two inner amplifiers have a gain of -0.5 and -2.4 resulting in an overall gain of 1.2.

Assuming that output is at the positive supply rail, this voltage is fed back to the input and is amplified by 1.2. Since the output of the opamp can't exceed the supply voltage, the output will remain constant.

Assuming a zero input voltage for this condition the output of the first opamp will be at -1/2 of the supply voltage. If now the input voltage is decreased the voltage at the output of the first opamp will increase until the the threshold is reached where the input voltage is too high so that the second opamp no longer provides the supply voltage at its output and the circuit toggles.

Update:
Another poster provided an answer with a detailed derivation showing that the circuit should have a gain of -6 and a few others seem to agree.

For this reason I'd like to point out where the problem with that other derivation is. The picture below shows a simulation of the circuit. The green trace is the input and the blue line shows the output of the circuit. So clearly, the gain is not -6 and the behavior described above can be seen.

[image]

Going back to the other poster's answer. At first glance, the derivation looks fine. However, the derivation was made under the assumption that the circuit is stable and that for this reason the differential voltage at the inputs of the opamps can be assumed to be zero. Neither is true. The linearized system is not stable, the circuit depends on the nonlinear behavior of the opamp to regain "stability".

The cyan trace of the simulation shows the input voltage of the second opamp. It can be seen that due to the nonlinear behavior the voltage difference at the input is no longer zero which violates an assumption made in that derivation.

Comment: This is not correct. See the comment thread with the question or Tim's answer for analysis of this circuit.

Comment: Tim's analysis is wrong.

Comment: I haven't looked at this closely, but if it has hysteresis, I can say confidently that this isn't an ideal op amp problem!

Comment: Can you simulate for small signals and huge power rails?

Comment: @ScottSeidman Shouldn't matter, supposedly the output is only 6x the input, so if it was just one op-amp, even a 741, you'd see "correct" behavior for input voltages about 1/10th of the supply rails, and that's not and won't ever be the case here. The assigned problem is a case of lack of forethought by the teacher or textbook author. There's no point doing such analysis on a circuit that won't work.

Comment: @KubaOber  -- the reason the output looks the way it does is because the first op amp saturates.  An ideal op amp cannot saturate.  Yes, the problem is not a realistic one, but I think the equations in the other solution and the comment thread hold under ideal assumptions.

Comment: @Scott Seidman The derivation is wrong even for ideal opamps. For ideal opamps the output would go to infinity and not saturate at the supply. You would never get a limited gain of -6.